# Stopping ArcGIS Desktop setting Gamma on raster load?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I often import raster files using GDAL utilities.  When those rasters are added to ArcGIS they seem to have a Gamma Stretch applied and a percent Clip stretch for RGB files.  Contrast ids also set to 10% by default.

Is there any way of creating an RGB geotif that ArcGIS will display with true RGB values instead of using default stretch values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### **Option 1:** Set the source type of a *single* raster to *"Processed"*

In **Arc Catalog**, open the *Raster Dataset Properties* of the GeoTiff. Browse to the *General* tab, and set the **Source Type** to ***"Processed"***.

[image: ArcGIS - Catalog - Raster Dataset Properties screenshot]

The different *Source Type* options are described in the [ArcGIS manual](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000018000000):

> The *Source Type* controls how the data is rendered by default. These options will be overridden if you modify the defaults. The options are:
>
> - Generic—Uses the application defaults for resampling and stretching.
> - Elevation—Applies bilinear resampling and a Min-Max stretch.
> - Thematic—Applies nearest neighbor resampling and a Standard Deviation stretch.
> - Processed—No stretch is applied.

For more details, have a look at the ArcGIS resource blog article [*"Stop stretching my imagery please"*](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/09/26/stop-stretching-my-imagery-please-part-2/).

### **Option 2:** Edit default stretching for *all* raster datasets

You can **change the default settings** of Raster display in the *ArcMap Options* dialog:

Within the ArcGIS menu, browse to *Customize -> ArcMap Options...*.

[image: ArcGIS menu screenshot]
In this dialogue, go to the *Raster* Tab and *Raster Layer* subtab.

Now **check *"Enable custom Rendering Defaults"*** and set *Stretch Type* and corresponding options as you like. In your case, set *Stretch Type* to *"None"* in order to import all your GeoTiff Images without any standard stretching applied.

[image: ArcMap Options dialogue screenshot]

A more detailed description of opening raster datasets with customized settings can be found in the [ArcGIS Resources blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/06/22/open-your-raster-data-with-customized-settings/).