# Change default color ramp in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, color-ramp

I would like to change the default color ramp that ArcMap uses when I add a new raster layer to my map.  [I found through the menu Customize/ArcMap Options.../Raster that I can change the Stretch Type](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87288/how-do-you-stop-arcgis-setting-gamma-on-raster-load/87296#87296), but I haven't found where to change the default white-to-black color ramp to a different, colored one.

This would be useful because I am adding many raster layers to my map and would need to change the color ramp (and stretch type) on each one manually.  I am exporting an image of each map made with a raster representing a different year to create an animation of change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an answer](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1730&t=272262) from the old Esri forums:

> You can change the default settings for ArcMap by running the AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe utility located here C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Utilities. This includes changing the default colour ramp, however I'm not sure if it will allow you to use a custom ramp or not.

Comment: I did not know about that utility--thanks.  However, changing the color ramp under the Symbols/Graphics tab, clicking Apply and Close, then closing and reopening ArcMap, did not change the default from the white-black color ramp.  Were you able to make this work?

Comment: My bad. I didn't test it out on my end before posting. It doesn't seem to affect the raster color ramp.